# while starting wildfly 10.1 to work with artemis, jboss.ra.activemq-ra is not installed error persists

Tags: messaging, wildfly-10, activemq-artemis

I try to apply appropriate configuration to be able to use remote messaging system on artemis server through wildfly (also other environment members)
Firstly, i installed a standalone artemis server(2.0) on my local ( https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?filename=activemq/activemq-artemis/2.0.0/apache-artemis-2.0.0-bin.zip&action=download ) 
Then i defined an example queueu on it. (exampleQueue) 
I changed the standalone.xml file according to informations on https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Connect+a+pooled-connection-factory+to+a+Remote+Artemis+Server
So, here is socket-binding-group:

```
    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
    ...
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="remote-artemis">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="61616"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

adapted messaging subsytem definition (had comprised embedded active-mq definitions and queues / topics before)

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:1.0">
        <server name="default">
            <remote-connector name="remote-artemis" socket-binding="remote-artemis"/>
            <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
            <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
                <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
            </http-acceptor>
            <pooled-connection-factory name="remote-artemis" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="remote-artemis" transaction="xa" user="s3artemisuser" password="s3artemispass"/>
        </server>
    </subsystem>
```

I also tried to include queues' jndi addresses essentially defined on remote artemis to be able to access from wildfly via injecting jndi resources. (followed this doc : https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/1.0.0/using-jms.html )

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
        <bindings>
            <external-context name="java:global/jms" module="org.jboss.as.naming" class="javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext" cache="true">
                <environment>
                    <property name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"/>
                    <property name="connectionFactory.ConnectionFactory" value="tcp://localhost:5445"/>
                    <property name="java.naming.security.principal" value="s3artemisuser"/>
                    <property name="java.naming.security.credentials" value="s3artemispass"/>
                </environment>
            </external-context>
        </bindings>
        <remote-naming/>
    </subsystem>
```

I have changed all resources injectin by jndi -temporarily to test- (which are used in producer and consumer classes)to refer remote queues/topics anymore.

```
class MyProducer extends BaseProducer {    
@Resource(mappedName = "java:/global/jms/exampleQueue")
private Queue aQueue;
...
public abstract class BaseProducer extends JpaService {

@Resource(mappedName = "java:/ConnectionFactory")
protected ConnectionFactory connectionFactory; ... }
```

When i start the wildfly with these configurations, services are not being deployed properly. Although i provide the activemq-rar-5.14.0.rar file under my deployment folder, still same error occurs. What am i missing here, what is the right configuration for my situation ?

```
10:19:13,701 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "my-module-using-jms-ear-2.0-SNAPSHOT.ear")]) - failure description: {
"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.ra.activemq-ra"],
"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
```

Answer (score 2):

Although I don't think my situation is really similar to what you're trying to achieve, it might prove useful as a comparison. (And since you asked for the details at [JMS Bridge Between WildFly 10 Artemis and ActiveMQ 5.14 (ONCE_AND_ONLY_ONCE Quality of Service)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508949/jms-bridge-between-wildfly-10-artemis-and-activemq-5-14-once-and-only-once-qual/39509748) I'll gladly postit here)

In my case I am using the built-in WildFly Artemis server and then configuring a JMS bridge which does ONCE_AND_ONLY_ONCE delivery to a remote ActiveMQ server.

Of course, you could potentially use a similar setup, but with Artemis as the remote server as well.

Since my remote server is ActiveMQ my RA file is different to yours, but the config should be similar.

Here's my DockerFile statements that copy and extract the RA in the correct location:

```
COPY activemq-ra.zip /opt/platoon/wildfly/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/apache/activemq/activemq/ra/activemq-ra.zip
WORKDIR /opt/platoon/wildfly/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/apache/activemq/activemq/ra
RUN unzip activemq-ra.zip
```

And here's the relevant section of my standalone-full.xml

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:1.0">
        <server name="default">
            <security-setting name="#">
                <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
            </security-setting>
            <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10"/>
            <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
            <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
                <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            </http-connector>
            <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
            <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
                <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
            </http-acceptor>
            <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
            <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
            <jms-queue name="testQueue" entries="queue/test java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/test"/>
            <jms-queue name="NonBridgedTestQueue" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/nonBridgedTestQueue"/>
            <jms-queue name="BridgedTestQueue" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/bridgedTestQueue"/>
            <jms-queue name="c3mMasterQueue" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/c3mMasterQueue"/>
            <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
            <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
            <connection-factory name="InVmXAConnectionFactory" entries="java:/XAConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" factory-type="XA_GENERIC"/>
            <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
        </server>
        <jms-bridge name="simple-jms-bridge" quality-of-service="ONCE_AND_ONLY_ONCE" failure-retry-interval="10000" max-retries="5" max-batch-size="10" max-batch-time="100" add-messageID-in-header="true">
            <source connection-factory="java:/XAConnectionFactory" destination="jboss/exported/jms/queue/c3mMasterQueue"/>
            <target connection-factory="jboss/activemq/activeMQXAConnectionFactory" destination="jboss/activemq/queue/c3mMasterQueue"/>
        </jms-bridge>
    </subsystem>

    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:4.0">
        <resource-adapters>
            <resource-adapter id="activemq">
        <module slot="main" id="org.apache.activemq.activemq.ra" />
                <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
                <config-property name="ServerUrl">
                    tcp://c3m-activemq:61616?jms.rmIdFromConnectionId=true
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="UserName">
                    admin
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="UseInboundSession">
                    false
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="Password">
                    admin
                </config-property>
                <connection-definitions>
                    <connection-definition class-name="org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/AMQConnectionFactory" enabled="true" pool-name="AMQConnectionFactory">
                        <xa-pool>
                            <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                            <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
                            <prefill>false</prefill>
                            <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
                        </xa-pool>
                    </connection-definition>
                </connection-definitions>
                <admin-objects>
                    <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:jboss/activemq/activeMQXAConnectionFactory" use-java-context="true" pool-name="activeMQXAConnectionFactory">
                        <config-property name="brokerURL">
                            tcp://c3m-activemq:61616?jms.rmIdFromConnectionId=true
                        </config-property>
                    </admin-object>
                    <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic" jndi-name="java:jboss/activemq/topic/TestTopic" use-java-context="true" pool-name="TestTopic">
                        <config-property name="PhysicalName">
                            activemq/topic/TestTopic
                        </config-property>
                    </admin-object>
                    <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" jndi-name="java:jboss/activemq/queue/c3mMasterQueue" use-java-context="true" pool-name="c3mMasterQueue">
                        <config-property name="PhysicalName">
                            activemq/queue/c3mMasterQueue
                        </config-property>
                    </admin-object>
                    <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" jndi-name="java:jboss/activemq/queue/bridgedTestQueue" use-java-context="true" pool-name="BridgedTestQueue">
                        <config-property name="PhysicalName">
                            activemq/queue/bridgedTestQueue
                        </config-property>
                    </admin-object>
                    <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" jndi-name="java:jboss/activemq/queue/TestQueue" use-java-context="true" pool-name="TestQueue">
                        <config-property name="PhysicalName">
                            activemq/queue/TestQueue
                        </config-property>
                    </admin-object>
                </admin-objects>
            </resource-adapter>
        </resource-adapters>
    </subsystem>
```

TAKE NOTE: I only edited the messaging-activemq and resource-adapters subsystems, i.e. I didn't touch any of the other sections (naming and socket-bindings) in standalone-full.xml like in your situation.

Hope that helps

Greg