# Wildfly 11 connection to remote Artemis ActiveMQ server configuration

Tags: wildfly, activemq-artemis, resource-adapter

It appears that the  netty-connector to the remote client is not happy!  For now, I have active my running on my local machine with the standard 616161 port.
I followed the directions at https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/Connect+a+pooled-connection-factory+to+a+Remote+Artemis+Server

Here is the error:

```
12:18:50,707 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) AMQ221007: Server is now live
12:18:50,707 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) AMQ221001: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 1.5.5.jbossorg-008 [default,    nodeID=de747bb0-bf64-11e7-9132-887873d0243d]
12:18:50,707 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) AMQ221003: Deploying queue jms.queue.DLQ
12:18:50,739 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) AMQ122005: Invalid "host" value "0.0.0.0" detected for "http-connector" connector. Switching to    " Demo-Laptop". If this new address is incorrect please manually configure the connector to use the proper one.
12:18:50,760 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
12:18:50,760 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/ConnectionFactory
12:18:50,760 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) AMQ221003: Deploying queue jms.queue.ExpiryQueue
12:18:50,776 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0007: Registered connection factory java:/jms/remoteCF
12:18:50,776 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0007: Registered connection factory java:/JmsXA
12:18:50,823 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra] (MSC service thread 1-3) Resource adaptor started
12:18:50,823 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.ResourceAdapterActivatorService$ResourceAdapterActivator] (MSC service thread 1-3) IJ020002: Deployed: file://RaActivatoractivemq-ra
12:18:50,823 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0002: Bound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
12:18:50,823 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory
12:18:51,077 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] (Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads)) AMQ214013: Failed to decode packet: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AMQ119032: Invalid type: 1
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.PacketDecoder.decode(PacketDecoder.java:424)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.ClientPacketDecoder.decode(ClientPacketDecoder.java:60)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.ClientPacketDecoder.decode(ClientPacketDecoder.java:39)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.bufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:355)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl$DelegatingBufferHandler.bufferReceived(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1143)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.ActiveMQChannelHandler.channelRead(ActiveMQChannelHandler.java:69)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:624)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:559)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:476)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:438)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

All messaging (both sending and receiving) is to be from the active mq server as the producer/consumer of the messages is legacy using ActiveMQ.

Added to my xml configuration copies from standard-full.xml

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
             …
    <outbound-socket-binding name="remote-artemis">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="61616"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:2.0">
        <server name="default">
                            <remote-connector name="remote-artemis" socket-binding="remote-artemis"/>
                            ……
                            <pooled-connection-factory name="remote-artemis" entries="java:/jms/remoteCF" connectors="remote-artemis" transaction="xa" user="admin" password="admin"/>
      </server>
```

I use a pooled connection factory because the documentation says “that it is essentially a configuration façade for both the inbound and outbound connectors of the Artemis JCA Resource Adapter.”
Which is exactly what I need.

My sending code looks like:

```
@Resource(lookup =" java:/jms/remoteCF")//java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory
 static ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

 @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/activemq/topic/POOPOITopic")
 private static Topic pointsTopic;

try {         
    if (connectionFactory == null)
      {
          logger.severe("not finding java:/jms/remoteCF");
      }
```

When I try to send, I get the connectionFactory as null!
My MDB looks like

```
@ResourceAdapter("remote-artemis")
//An MDB can be configured to use a pooled-connection-factory (e.g. using @ResourceAdapter). 
// In this context, the MDB leverages the inbound connector of the Artemis JCA RA.  Other kinds of clients    
//     can look up the pooled-connection-factory in JNDI (or inject it) and use it to send messages.  In this context, such a client would leverage the outbound connector of the Artemis JCA RA.  
@Inject
@JMSConnectionFactory("java:/jms/remoteCF")
private JMSContext context;
```

What am I missing? All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I gave up on this approach and am attempting the bridge as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43179283/while-starting-wildfly-10-1-to-work-with-artemis-jboss-ra-activemq-ra-is-not-in

Comment: Thank you Greg Fullard for posting your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue (also following wildfly documentation) but this worked fine.

```
Context jndiContext = new InitialContext();
connectionFactory =  (ConnectionFactory)jndiContext.lookup( "java:/jms/remoteCF" );
```

Be aware that what you get here is not JMSContext but ConnectionFactory. It can do all the same things it's just a different API.